# Where is the glass button on the materials list?

Tags: texturing

I was watching a YouTube video and it showed how to get a mesh to look like glass but the surface folder in materials is not there on my bender

Comment: What render engine are you using?

Comment: What tutorial were you watching? There is no such thing as "surface folder", there may be a non standard addon used.

Comment: Well not surface folder, but when you go into the materials for an object it should say "Surface" for one of the options but mine does not say that. Tutorial is Blender guru light bulb part 2 of 2

Comment: Switch your render engine to Cycles

Comment: You just saved my grade from being an F

Answer (score 1):

Go in to Cycles Render Engine with the Selector at the top of the User Interface then in the Materials tab create a Material and if needed click use Nodes then there should ba a Surface tab below.